# Templating engine which can record some block position

Tags: python, templates, python-2.7

I am writing a email client and I want to implement a thing like `%CURSOR` from kmail templates: mark a position where cursor should be put after generated email message was displayed. What template engine can do this type of thing?

Comment: How is this related to Python?

Comment: @Amber Because I need python templating engine. It is not directly related to kmail: I am writing mail client, not plugin to kmail. `kmail` is here for example only.

Comment: I don't think you want to handle cursor position in your templating engine. Instead, I'd say just have a token that you detect later and remove from the rendered template to place the cursor at.

Comment: @Amber This is what I will fallback to if I do not find such engine. But having such token means that I have to either add additional unescaping rules to be able to escape it (and add escaping rules to used templating engine) or be completely unable to have this token in the generated message. Any token I use will be the problem in the situation “I quote a message which quotes my message where I write about this token” which is going to happen if I will talk about new email client on some mailing list, for example.

Comment: You're going to run into that issue regardless, because template engines don't have control over your UI directly, so they're still going to need to pass through some kind of token to the rest of your application.

Comment: @Amber It is not a problem here: if I can make template engine put offset at the last line then I will know that last line is *always* offset and thus it does not need escaping. I can’t see a way to do the same without support from template engine: in this case information about where cursor position is located is unknown and everything except marker needs to be escaped.

Comment: I now guessed a third option though: split at marker and pass two templates to engine instead of one. This means marker will be processed before processing template and the above mentioned problem does not exist, but this also means that things like `{% set var = value %}` (jinja) are not going to work as expected.

Comment: Another thing: template engines (at least, jinja and cheetah) allow to call python functions and it is not guaranteed they do not have side effects. If function is a closure that modifies a dictionary in an outer scope as a side effect then template engine does not need to pass any kind of token anywhere, it just needs to pass current offset to this function.

Comment: Seems like it is possible to do by using mako, subclassing mako.runtime.Context overriding its write() method to write to a known class member and adding get_offset() method (I believe it can be done with original Context, but it is not documented where write() method writes to).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from mako.runtime import Context
class CursorContext(Context):
    __slots__=set(('lines', 'position'))

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CursorContext, self.__class__).__init__(self, self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.lines=['']
        self.position=None

    def write(self, v):
        ls=s(v).split('\n')
        self.lines[-1]+=ls.pop(0)
        self.lines+=ls

    def _record_position(self):
        if self.position is not None:
            raise ValueError('Position already defined')
        self.position=(len(self.lines), len(self.lines[-1]) if self.lines else 0)

    def _get_position(self):
        if self.position is None:
            self._record_position()
        return self.position

<...>

context=CursorContext(**env) # env is a dictionary with template environment variables
template.render_context(context) # template is mako.template.Template object
# Now template is in context.lines and 
# cursor position can be obtained by context._get_position()
```